# Laravel 4: How to load other method in a controller?

Tags: php, function, controller, laravel, laravel-4

This is one of my controller:

```
class MediaController extends BaseController {

    private $js_files = array(), $css_files = array();

    /** Media specific function **/

    static function base_uri(){
        return sprintf(
            "%s://%s%s",
            isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        );
    }

    function AddJquery($version = null) {
        if($version === null) $version = 'custom';
        $js_files[] = '<script src="assets/js/jquery/jquery.' . $version . '.js"></script>';
    }

    function AddJS($name, $minified = true) {
        $js_base_uri = base_uri() . "assets/js/";
        $js_files[] = $js_base_uri . ($minified ? '/min/' : '') . $name . ($minified ? '.min' : '') . '.js';
    }

    /** Page specific function **/

    public function index_page() {
        if(!empty($js_files)) $js_files = array();
        if(!empty($css_files)) $css_files = array();

        AddJquery();
        AddJS('mainscript');

        $data = array(
            'js_files' => $js_files
        );

        return View::make('homepage', $data);
    }
}   

?>
```

When I access my main page with `Route::get('/', 'MediaController@index_page');`
in routes.php, in the `index_page()` it cannot access `AddJquery()` method.

Anyone can tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: You need to call `$this->AddJS(...` not just `AddJS(...`.

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot `$this`. Thanks, almost wasted a lot of time :D